# stack peek method using SLL return object address instead of actual value

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

The implementation of SLL is in another module and I have imported that into the current working module.
This method returns the address of cur_node instead of the actual value I also have the repr method in my program it works fine on other outputs such as push pop etc but not on peek.

```
def peek(self):
    cur_node = self.head
    while True:
        if cur_node.next is None:
            return cur_node
        cur_node = cur_node.next
```

the repr method is the following.

```
def __repr__(self):
    nodes = []
    cur_node = self.head
    while cur_node:
        nodes.append(f"{cur_node.data}")
        cur_node = cur_node.next
    return ','.join(nodes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in returning the actual value (see commented line):

```py
def peek(self):
    cur_node = self.head
    while True:
        if cur_node.next is None:
            return cur_node.data # Return data and not object
        cur_node = cur_node.next
```